# How to display saved filters in headers with PrimeNG?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I am able to save the filters locally using `stateStorage="local"` `stateKey="myKey"`.  So when the user leaves the component and returns, the data is still filtered based upon whatever filters they have set.

The problem is, the user has no idea what they are filtering on anymore, as the filter headers do not show them anything anymore, just the default label.  I can access the filters via local storage, and delete them using `localStorage.removeItem("myKey");`, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this filter information to display in the filter headers.  We are not using lazyLoad, as suggested in another answer.  You'd think this would be built in any time a filter is saved because not knowing what you are filtering on seems like a major flaw.

For more clarity, I have attached the primeFaces documentation below.  If you select 'Red' 'White' and 'Green' from the multiselect dropdown, it will display your selected filter in the header (Red, White, Green) above.  I need this information to display anytime the user enters the component if they have filters saved (both with text input, and with the dropdowns).

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/filter

I am using multi-select dropdown filters, text input, as well as calendar filters. Here is a snippet of the html, which includes examples of these three filter types:

```
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">                                               
      <input *ngSwitchCase="'userID'" pInputText type="text" size="12" placeholder="contains" (input)="table.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)" [value]="table.filters['userID'] ? table.filters['userID'].value : ''">       
      <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
        <p-calendar #calendar1 class="ui-fluid" *ngSwitchCase="'myDate'" [monthNavigator]="true" [showOnFocus]="false" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2010:2060" [showIcon]="true" 
          [showOtherMonths]="false" [showButtonBar]="true" [appendTo]="attach"  [style]="{'overflow': 'visible'}" 
          [(ngModel)]="calendar1Filter" 
          (ngModelChange)="table.filter($event, 'myDate', calendar1Option)"                                                                                 
          (onSelect)="table.filter($event, 'myDate', calendar1Option)">
            <p-footer>  
                <div class="ui-grid-row">
                    <div class="ui-grid-col-3"><label style="font-weight: bold; color: #337ab7">Mode:</label></div>                     
                    <div class="ui-grid-col-6"><p-dropdown [options]="calendar1Options" [style]="{'width':'60px', 'padding-top': '0px'}" [(ngModel)]="calendar1Option" (onChange)="onChangeModCalOpt(calendar1, 1)" ></p-dropdown> </div>
                </div>
             </p-footer>
         </p-calendar>   
       </div>                                  
      <div class="ui-fluid">
        <p-multiSelect *ngSwitchCase="'myDropdown'" appendTo="body" [options]="dropdownOptions" pInputText type="text" size="12" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" defaultLabel="All" [(ngModel)]="myDropdownFilter" (onChange)="table.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in')"></p-multiSelect>
      </div>
     </th>
```

Comment: Can you provide the component.html of the table?  Are the filters in the header input, select box, or both ?

Comment: Added an example of the filters I'm using. It is select box and input as well as calendars.

Answer (score 0):

I did this almost a year ago; it involved some tricky code, as you'll see below, because the table element was beneath an `*ngIf` directive. I'm not sure if your case is the same, but if it is, here's what I had to to do get it to work. In the example, I have a `fooTable` that has a custom filter on the `status` column.

`foo.component.ts`:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector    : 'foo',
    templateUrl : 'foo.component.html'
})
export class FooComponent {
    // members /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    showFooTable: boolean  = true;
    statusFilter: string[] = [];

    // constructor(s) //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    // getters and setters /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Due to the Angular lifecycle, we have to do some tricky things here to pull the filters from the session,
     * if they are present. The workarounds done in this function are as follows:
     *
     * 1) Wait until the element is accessible. This is not until the *ngIf is rendered, which is the second call to
     *    this function. The first call is simply 'undefined', which is why we check for that and ignore it.
     * 2) Check and see if the filters for this object are even part of the template. If not, just skip this step.
     * 3) If we find the filters in the session, then change this object's filters model to equal it and call the change
     *    detection manually to prevent Angular from throwing an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error
     * @param fooTable the reference to the foo table template
     */
    @ViewChild('fooTable') set fooTable(fooTable: any) {
        if(fooTable != undefined) {
            let filters = fooTable.filters['status'];
            if (filters != undefined && filters.value != undefined) {
                this.statusFilter = filters.value;
            }
            this.cd.detectChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

`foo.component.html`:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="showFooTable">
    <div id="filters">
        <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="statusFilter" value="up"      (onChange)="fooTable.filter(statusFilter, 'status', 'in')"></p-checkbox> Up
        <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="statusFilter" value="down"    (onChange)="fooTable.filter(statusFilter, 'status', 'in')"></p-checkbox> Down
        <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="statusFilter" value="unknown" (onChange)="fooTable.filter(statusFilter, 'status', 'in')"></p-checkbox> Unknown
    </div>

    <p-table #fooTable
             stateStorage="session"
             stateKey="foo-table-state">
    </p-table>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turbo tables filters can be access like so. `table.filters['myColumn']?.value`.  You will need to set the input values in the header, `[value]="table.filters[col.field]?.value"`

```js
...
<tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field" class="ui-fluid">
        <input pInputText 
               type="text"
               (input)="table.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)"
               [value]="table.filters[col.field]?.value">
    </th>
</tr>
...
```

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/state

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out. What I ended up doing was attaching the default label to a model like so:

```
<p-multiSelect [defaultLabel]="table.filters[col.field]?.value || 'All'">
```

If the table has the filter value in its state, it will populate the label else default to 'All'.